# Clarification on entering San Francisco International Airport (SFO) from Guam via Narita International Airport (NRT)

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, sfo, nrt, guam

I am a Indian Passport holder with a valid H1B Visa. 
I am travelling from SFO to Guam via Honolulu. But for my return travel to SFO from Guam, I am transiting via NRT.

Ideally, I am not leaving US except transiting through NRT. 
So, if I leave for NRT from Guam, will my I94 be taken from my passport? Also, if I am entering SFO, should I have to get a new I94?

Either way, is it safe to do this travel via NRT or will I face any issues in SFO immigration?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, your I94 will be taken out of the passport when you are leaving from Guam to Japan. You will have to fill out a new one once you enter US territory again. The only exception for this rule is when you [go to Canada or Mexico](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form_I-94) for less than 30 days.

This is a completely normal procedure and pretty much the same anywhere else in the world. If your visa for the USA allows multiple entries (your H1B visa does), you simply fill out the form again and show that along with the multiple entry visa at the immigration.

However, if you will be doing this from middle of May 2013 on or later, you do not need to fill out the i94 anyhow, since the [process will be automated](http://www.cbp.gov/xp/cgov/travel/id_visa/i-94_instructions/i94_rollout.xml), and the data will be retrieved from the airline directly.